# How do I add a threshold to the model.decision_function?

Tags: python, data-science, svm, confusion-matrix

Question is: How do I add a threshold to a model.decision_function (in this case model=Support Vector Clustering Machine and I want the output in a confusion matrix; this is a binary classification of 1's and 0's where the 1's will be above the -210 threshold)

Below is what I have so far, but it gives a weird output so it's not right. It's too difficult to include the data; I'm just hoping someone has done something similar to this before and knows what I might be missing in my code.

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
> 
> def test():
>     svm = SVC(kernel='linear').fit(X_train, y_train)
>     svm_predicted = np.where(svm.decision_function(X_test)>-210,1,0)
>     confusion = confusion_matrix(y_test, svm_predicted)
>     return confusion
> 
> test()
```

Output:

```
> array([[  0, 750],
>        [  0, 320]])
```

Thank you in advance for any pointers or guidance!

Comment: Are you sure this threshold is right? `svm.decision_function(X_test)>-210`, seems to be what is causing that only 1 is predicted

Comment: Have you had a look at y_test and y_pred?

Comment: thanks, yatu, for your response; I'm sure about the -210 but I'm not sure I coded it correctly if that makes sense; I know that X_test and y_test both have the same count of 1070 and output adds up to 1070 (output is showing 750+320 and that equals the 1070; however, it's not distributing correctly in the confusion matrix; thanks for your help